# Scrapy and Selenium error : Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up Stacktrace

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

I want to extract data from Amazon.
This is my source code :

```
    from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider
    from scrapy import Selector
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
    from time import sleep
    import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
    from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher
    from scrapy.http import HtmlResponse, TextResponse
    from extraction.items import ProduitItem

    class RunnerSpider(CrawlSpider):
      name = 'products'
      allowed_domains = ['amazon.com']
      start_urls = ['http://www.amazon.com']

      def __init__(self):
         self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()

     def parse(self, response):
        items = []
        sel = Selector(response)
        self.driver.get(response.url)
        recherche = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="twotabsearchtextbox"]')
        recherche.send_keys("A")
        recherche.submit()
        resultat = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//ul[@id="s-results-list-atf"]')
        resultas = resultat.find_elements_by_xpath('//li')
        for result in resultas:
          item = ProduitItem()
          lien = result.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="s-item-container"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a')
          lien.click()
          #lien.implicitly_wait(2)
          res = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[@id="aiv-content-title"]')
          item['TITRE'] = res.text
          item['IMAGE'] = lien.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="dv-dp-left-content"]/div[1]/div/div/img').get_attribute('src')
          items.append(item)

        self.driver.close()
        yield items
```

When I run my code I get this error :

```
Element not found in the cache - perhaps the page has changed since it was looked up Stacktrace:
```

Comment: This error is caused by these instructions :  lien = result.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="s-item-container"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a')  
          lien.click()  
          
          res = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//h1[@id="aiv-content-title"]')  
          item['TITRE'] = res.text

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31549459/edit) your question instead of commenting if you have additional details to add.

Comment: Ok I got the problem but any solution or help to offer me?

Answer (score 1):

If you tell Selenium to click on a likn you are moved from the original page to the page behind the link.

In your case you have a result site with some URLs to products on Amazon then you click one of the links in this result list and are moved to the detail site. In this case the site changes and the rest of the elements you want to iterate over in your `for` loop is not there -- that's why you get the exception.

Why don't you use the search result site to extract the title and the image? Both are there you would only need to change the XPath expressions to get the right fields of your `lien`.

**Update**

To get the Title from the search result site extract the text in the `h2` element of the `a` element you want to click.

To get the image you need to take the other `div` in the `li` element: where in your XPath you select `div[2]` you need to select `div[1]` to get the image.

If you open the search result site in the browser and look at the sources with developer tools you can see which XPath expression to use for the elements.

Comment: Please can you explain me how I can use the search result site to extract the title and the image?  @GHajba

Comment: Please, Which element should I use to extract the title and the image: self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('') or lien.find_element_by_xpath() ? @GHajba

Comment: For the title `lien` because it is the link. For the image you need to use `result` with a bit different XPath for the image.

Comment: Please, I tested : item['Title'] = result.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="s-item-container"]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/a/h2').text , item['Title'] = lien.find_element_by_xpath('//h2') and item['Title']=self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@id="a-page"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/h1[@id="aiv-content-title"]').text , but I don't get any result. Thank you for all and any help you are able to offer me @GHajba

Comment: Did you try to call `lien.find_element_by_xpath('./h2')` because you look for one element and in the link there is only one h2 available. And I hope you did remove the `lien.click()` command too.

Comment: I use lien.click() to go to the product's details web page that contain ( image, price, description,…) @GHajba